# how to choose file with certain extension? ruby

Tags: ruby, file, parsing, search

I want ruby to look for a file in the current folder that ends with a certain extension. The extension would be .app.zip

How would I do this?

Answer (score 6):

To get the first matching file in the current directory, you can use:

```
file=Dir['*.app.zip'].first
```

Or to find all .app.zip files in certain directory, for example files/*.app.zip, you can use something like :

```
Dir[File.join('files', '*.app.zip')].each |file|
  puts "found: #{file}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Dir:

```
require "find"

Find.find(folder) do |file|
  puts "#{file}" if file=~/\.app\.zip/
end
```